# Using Big.matrix values without [...]

Tags: r, matrix, largenumber, ehcache-bigmemory

Using the package **bigmemory** and **bigalgebra** I wanted just to ask: Is there a way to use data of the big.matrix in some function without getting the `Error: argument 'x' must be numeric.` 
I would like to use the elements of big.matrix to compute density.

Example:

```
x <- sample(1:10, 20,TRUE)
x <- as.numeric(x)
x_mat <- matrix(x, ncol=20)
x_big <- as.big.matrix(x)

x_cros <- x_big %*% x_mat
kd <- density(x_cros, bw="nrd0")
Error: argument 'x' must be numeric.
```

Comment: see the edited version

Comment: I'm afraid that the only solution you have is to write a `density` method for your `big.matrix` object using Cpp. Check the Rcpp gallery to see how to manipulate `big.matrix` object or better check the implementation of `biganalytics::bigkmeans` to implement your `density` function.